# PostgreSQL 9.5: On conflict update with CTE

Tags: postgresql

I have the following three tables with two columns for each table.

**Table**: ct1

```
create table ct1
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(10)
);
```

**Table**: ct2

```
create table ct2 
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(10)
);
```

**Table**: ct3

```
create table ct3
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into ct1 values(1,'A');
insert into ct1 values(2,'B');

insert into ct1 values(11,'C');
insert into ct1 values(12,'D');
```

**Note**: I want to insert the record in the tab  table ct3 by select the data from other two table's using CTE(mandatory).

## My try:

**Query**:

```
INSERT INTO ct3(id,name)
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT id,name from ct1 
    WHERE id is not null
),
cte2
as
(
    SELECT id,name from ct2
    WHERE name is not null
)
select c1.id as id1,c2.name as name1 from cte as c1,cte2 as c2
on conflict (id) do update
set
id = id1,
name = name1;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  column "id1" does not exist
LINE 17:  id = id1,
```

Comment: `from cte as c1,cte2 as c2` looks wrong. Do you **really** want a **cross** join (cartesian product) between the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

The insert needs to be the final query **after** the CTEs

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT id,name from ct1 
    WHERE id is not null
),
cte2
as
(
    SELECT id,name from ct2
    WHERE name is not null
)
INSERT INTO ct3(id,name) --<< INSERT needs to go here
select c1.id as id1,c2.name as name1 
from cte as c1,
     cte2 as c2 --<< are you SURE you want a cross join here? 
on conflict (id) do update
-- no need to update the ID column here as that is the one used for conflict detection
set name = name1;
```

Comment: What is the point of the conflict update using the same values which would have been inserted (I'm not questioning your syntax)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: good point. I just did a copy and paste of that part.